# I am an Indian citizen touring Australia on a visit visa. Can I apply for NZ visa from Australia?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, new-zealand

I am living currently in Australia on a tourist visa. I want to Visit New Zealand too. Can I apply for a visitor's visa to NZ from Australia? I hold an Indian passport.

Answer (score 4):

The information that is available there is no requirement on an Indian citizen to have residency in the country where he or she is applying from.

On the [NZ Immigration site](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/) you can use the [Eligibility Calculator](https://visaoptions.immigration.govt.nz/Home/CommonPersonal.aspx) to see what's available for you to apply.

The applications in Australia are processed by [TT Services](https://www.ttsnzvisa.com/Home) so you can contact them for additional information on the visa.